# Google doesn't show "www" in results

Tags: google, domains, google-search, no-www

After searching my site on Google I have found that the URL that is shown doesn't contain `www` at the beginning, why?

This is my virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName estebancortijo.com

  Redirect / http://www.estebancortijo.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.estebancortijo.com

  SetEnv MYAPP_ENV prod

  DocumentRoot /var/www/jesusesteban/web
  <Directory /var/www/jesusesteban/web/>
      # Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride None
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
      <IfModule mod_mime.c>
          Addtype font/truetype .ttf
          AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css font/opentype font/truetype
      </IfModule>
      <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
          Options -MultiViews

          RewriteEngine On
          #RewriteBase /path/to/app
          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
          RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
      </IfModule>
      <IfModule mod_expires.c>
          ExpiresActive On
      ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 days"
      ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
      ExpiresByType text/plain "access plus 1 month"
      ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
      ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
      ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
      ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
      ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
      ExpiresByType application/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
      </IfModule>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have the same configuration for another site, but in that case the `www` is shown in Google results.

Any idea?

Comment: @ John Conde - Thanks for the great info but i don't know why i am not able to set my preferred domain for one blog its - Dreamtechie.com ..

Answer (score 3):

If you want to explicitly tell Google to show your domain with the `www` you can [set your preferred domain in your Google Webmaster Account](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/44231?hl=en).

> The preferred domain is the one that you would liked used to index
>   your site's pages (sometimes this is referred to as the canonical
>   domain). Links may point to your site using both the www and non-www
>   versions of the URL (for instance, `http://www.example.com` and
>   `http://example.com`). The preferred domain is the version that you want
>   used for your site in the search results.
>
> If you see a message that your site is not indexed, it may be because
>   it is indexed under a different domain. For example, if you receive a
>   message that `http://example.com` is not indexed, make sure that you've
>   also added `http://www.example.com` to your account (or vice versa), and
>   check the data for that site.
>
> Once you tell us your preferred domain name, we use that information
>   for all future crawls of your site and indexing refreshes. For
>   instance, if you specify your preferred domain as
>   `http://www.example.com` and we find a link to your site that is
>   formatted as `http://example.com`, we follow that link as
>   `http://www.example.com` instead. In addition, we'll take your
>   preference into account when displaying the URLs. If you don't specify
>   a preferred domain, we may treat the www and non-www versions of the
>   domain as separate references to separate pages.
>
> It may take some time before you see this change fully reflected in
>   our index. All pages that currently display the non-preferred version
>   of the URL in the index will remain in the index that way until we
>   refresh our indexing of those pages.
>
> Specify a preferred domain:
>
> 1.On the Webmaster Tools Home page, click the site you want.
>
> 2.Click the gear icon , and then click Site Settings.
>
> 3.In the Preferred domain section, select the option you want.
>
> You may need to verify ownership of both the www and non-www versions
>   of your domain. Because setting a preferred domain impacts both
>   crawling and indexing, we need to ensure that you own both versions.
>   Typically, both versions point to the same physical location, but this
>   is not always the case. Generally, once you have verified one version
>   of the domain, we can easily verify the other using the original
>   verification method. However, if you've removed the file, meta tag, or
>   DNS record, you'll need to repeat the verification steps.
>
> Note: Once you've set your preferred domain, you may want to use a 301
>   redirect to redirect traffic from your non-preferred domain, so that
>   other search engines and visitors know which version you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

As bybe pointed out, you are redirecting from `non-www` prefix to `www` prefix URLs, which is normally enough to change the way URLs are listed the SERPs.

However the redirect is incorrectly defined as a temporary 302 redirected. 302 redirects are notorious for causing issues in Google cache and you should be using a permanent 301 redirect instead.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your site. Your site is enforcing `www`. which means that it's impossible to access your site without `www`. since the browser will redirect. Since the Googlebot would be redirected as a user would Google would not index `no-www` URLs unless both `www`. and `no-www` versions were accessible.

From the looks of it, you have recently enforced `www`. Within your vhost conf file, Google is renowned for taking weeks, months and in some cases can take a whole year depending on the volume of URLs.

I believe that Google does this on purpose, obviously it doesn't want webmasters constantly changing URLS but also it doesn't want to quickly index something that could be a webmaster hiccup with consequences of hurting his or her rankings, so I believe that Google will monitor the page, and site then after X crawls it'll reflect those changes. Now how many crawls, time or what not is anyone's guess but this is completely normal.

Google is aware of your changes since I can see newer pages with `www`. in the index, to answer your question and correct me if I'm wrong in anyway, you just need to wait longer!